# How to fix Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {server ip}:9042

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect spark and Cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector. the connection gets established but when i am trying to perform operations on JavaRDD i am facing.

```
   java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {10.0.21.92}:9042
```

Here is the configuration and code which i am trying to implement :

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Data Transformation").set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").setMaster("local[4]");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", server ip);
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "5000");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms", "200000");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", user_name);
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password);

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

And below is the code where i am performing operation on javardd:

```
    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable(keySpaceName, tableName);
    JavaRDD<GenericTriggerEntity> rdd = cassandraRDD.map(new Function<CassandraRow, GenericTriggerEntity>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -165799649937652815L; 

    @Override
    public GenericTriggerEntity call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
    GenericTriggerEntity genericTriggerEntity = new GenericTriggerEntity();
    if(row.getString("end") != null)                        genericTriggerEntity.setEnd(row.getString("end"));
    if(row.getString("key") != null)
    genericTriggerEntity.setKey(row.getString("key"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setKeyspacename(row.getString("keyspacename"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setPartitiondeleted(row.getString("partitiondeleted"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setRowdeleted(row.getString("rowDeleted"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setRows(row.getString("rows"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setStart(row.getString("start"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setTablename("tablename");
    genericTriggerEntity.setTriggerdate(row.getString("triggerdate"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setTriggertime(row.getString("triggertime"));
    genericTriggerEntity.setUuid(row.getUUID("uuid"));
    return genericTriggerEntity;
    }               

    });
```

Here is the JavaRDD operation i am performing

```
    JavaRDD<String> jsonDataRDDwords = rdd.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split((CharSequence) s)));
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> jsonDataRDDones = jsonDataRDDwords.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> jsonDataRDDcounts = jsonDataRDDones.reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> jsonDatRDDoutput = jsonDataRDDcounts.collect();
```

I even tried telnet to Cassandra server the port is open.

I am able to establish the connection but then while performing reduceByKey getting the above exception.

I am not able to figure out what is the issue. Is something wrong in the javardd operation.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you try to execute `cqlsh IP` ?

Comment: i installed Cassandra on my local and tried cqlsh 127.0.0.0 it gives error 

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.0': error(101, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.0', 9042)]. Last error: Network is unreachable")})

Comment: try `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Yup got connected with 127.0.0.1 but didn't solve the native connection issue.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error was due to some dependency issue of cassandra drive core.
solved it by adding metric dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
<artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use socat command to forward your local port to your remote cassandra port:

```
apt-get install socat
socat tcp-listen:9042,fork tcp:10.0.21.92:9042 &
```